# Why the interate function print at first than randQuestion function prints?

Tags: javascript

```js
var Question = function(question, answer, correctAnswer) {
  this.question = question;
  this.answer = answer;
  this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
}

var quesArray = new Array();

quesArray.push(new Question('Is java script instresting?', ['yes', 'no', 'TBD'], 0));
quesArray.push(new Question('Who is the course teacher?', ['Mark', 'Jane', 'Jonas'], 3));
quesArray.push(new Question('What do u thing about codding? ', ['Fedup', 'Interesting', 'Okay'], 2));

function iterate(answer) {
  for (var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
    console.log(answer[i]);
  }
}

function randQuestion() {
  var rand = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()) * 2;
  var ques = quesArray[rand];
  console.log(ques.question + '\n' + iterate(ques.answer));
}
randQuestion();
```

Output:-

Mark

Jane

Jonas script

Who is the course teacher?

undefined

### ---------------------------------------------------

What i think it should be?

Who is the course teacher?

Mark

Jane

Jonas script

Comment: BTW `Math.floor(Math.random())` is always `0`. Also, `quesArray = new Array()`, come on! Would it kill you if you do `quesArray = []`?!

Comment: You used 3 as the correct answer although the arraylist doesn't have index 3, because it's length is 3 you should write 2 to get the last element.

Answer (score 2):

`iterate` isn't returning anything. If you wanted to use it in

```
console.log(ques.question + '\n' + iterate(ques.answer));
```

then you should have `iterate` return a string, probably `join`ing the `answer` array.

Another problem is that `rand` will always equal `1`. If you want an *actually* random question, use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)`:

```js
var Question = function (question, answer, correctAnswer) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
}

var quesArray = [];

quesArray.push(new Question('Is java script instresting?', ['yes', 'no', 'TBD'], 0));
quesArray.push(new Question('Who is the course teacher?', ['Mark', 'Jane', 'Jonas'], 3));
quesArray.push(new Question('What do u thing about codding? ', ['Fedup', 'Interesting', 'Okay'], 2));

function iterate(answer) {
  return answer.join('\n');
}

function randQuestion() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    var ques = quesArray[rand];
    console.log(ques.question + '\n' + iterate(ques.answer));
}
randQuestion();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(ques.question + '\n' + iterate(ques.answer));
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this gets evaluated first
```

In a function call, the parameter is always evaluated before the function gets called, otherwise how does the parameter get passed?

`ques.question + '\n' + iterate(ques.answer)` gets evaluated first, then `console.log` gets called.

Since `iterate` doen't return anything, `undefined` is assumed, thus `ques.question + '\n' + iterate(ques.answer)` evaluates to `"some question\nundefined"`.

Change `iterate` such that it returns the answers instead of logging them:

```
function iterate(answer) {
    var answersText = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
        answersText += answer[i] + "\n";
    }
    return answersText;
}
```

Or simply using a `join` for that:

```
function iterate(answer) {
    return answer.join("\n");
}
```